Broken automatic parameter injection of Connexion 2.7.0 when used with OpenAPI 3.0.0
I have a Flask backend which uses Connexion 2.7.0 with OpenAPI 3.0.0.
My swagger.yaml file is defined like this:
openapi: 3.0.0
info:
  title: MyApp
  version: "1.0"
paths:
  /run_recon:
    post:
      summary: run_recon
      operationId: services.model.run_recon
      requestBody:
        content:
          application/json:
            schema:
              type: object
        x-name: payload
        x-body-name: payload
      responses:
        "200":
          description: response
          content:
            "application/json":
              schema:
                type: object
      security:
        - jwt-user: ["secret"]

swagger.yaml is loaded into connexion app like this:
logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stdout, level=logging.DEBUG)
load_dotenv()
options = {"swagger_ui": True,
           "debug": True}
app = connexion.App(__name__, server='gevent')
app.add_api('swagger.yaml', options=options)
app.app.config["JSON_SORT_KEYS"] = False
app.app.wsgi_app = CorsHeaderMiddleware(app.app.wsgi_app)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("DB_NAME:",os.getenv("DB_NAME"))
    app.run(port=5002, host='0.0.0.0')

And the Python function in Flask app is defined like this:
def run_recon(payload):
    print("[run_recon]")

When the frontend sends request to /run_recon, the request does not even reach the Python function.
But if I simply change the function signature to: def run_recon(body), then the rqeeust reaches and the function works.
Why is the custom name for the request body breaking the automatic parameter injection of Connexion?
I have tried individually x-body and x-body-name, as well as using both together. Nothing seems to work.
